# Where could the error be in this programme, please?

Tags: python, string, split

I am grouped into groups for a project, and I am are expected to come up with as many famous scientists who have the same first letter of their name as I as possible. But I need to know whether i will have to come up with the answers on my own, or is there somebody in my group that I can work with?

The input is a string of my group members' names separated by spaces, and then a string of my name.

Expected Output: 
A string that says `"Compare notes"` if I have a name buddy, or `"No such luck"` if I have to work on this alone.

```
group_members = input().split()
my_name = input()
for fellow in group_members:
    if fellow[0] is my_name[0]:
        print("Compare notes")
        break
    else:
        print("No such luck")
        break
```

My programme worked perfectly for all but one of the test cases. Please, where could the bug be here? Thanks for your support.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to include sample input and expected output, and how the actual output was different than expected. "Worked for all but one test case" isn;t particularly useful unless you provide the test case

Comment: Welcome to SO. You may want to read [ask] and [mcve] and edit your question accordingly. NB : [mcve] means that we can copy paste your code, run it and get the _exact_ same result as you do.

Comment: Remove the first `break`.

Comment: I echo everything the previous comments say, and am also guessing you want to print "No such luck" after the loop, not every iteration if the the first letter does not match.

Comment: Two obvious issues though: 1/ if that's really how your code is indented,  then it will exit the loop on the first test that fails,  and 2/ you want to use equality test (`==`), not identity test (`is`) - it currently only "kind of" work due to CPython caching some strings, but that's an implementation detail you must not rely upon.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
group_members = input().split()
my_name = input()
for fellow in group_members:
    if fellow[0] == my_name[0]:
        print("Compare notes")
        break
else:
    print("No such luck")
```

More on `else` for the `for` loop is in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops).

Comment: The equality operator is `==` - `is` is the identity operator

Comment: It's absolutely irrelevant, both is and == yield exactly the same results, all tests passed except that stubborn hidden one

Comment: @mko77 try adding some code for edge cases like an empty `goup_members` list, empty `my_name` and such